# Howto get a list of user apps only in android?

Tags: java, android, launcher

i'm trying to create a simple apps launcher for android but when i try to get all apps in a list and use it to fill a recyclerview i get system apps and system services only while i'd want to show user apps only (eg. Whatsapp, Play Store, Calculator. Gallery, ecc), here's what i've tried:

```
public AppListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    appList = new ArrayList<>();

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    String this_app_name = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    List<ResolveInfo> allApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 1);
    for (ResolveInfo ri : allApps) {
        String app_name = ri.loadLabel(pm).toString();

        if (!app_name.contains(this_app_name)) {
            appList.add(ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
        }
    }


    Collections.sort(appList, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

// installed applications
List<ApplicationInfo> appList = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

ArrayList<PackageInfo> userApps = new ArrayList();

//check if the application is a user app
for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : appList) {
    if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
        // This is a user app
        userApps.add(appInfo);
    }
}

// Now the userApps ArrayList contains the package names of all user apps
package names
for (String package : userApps) {
    Log.d("MyApp", "User app: " + package.packageName);
}
```